# Qt VS Tools does not work in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, qt

The Qt VS Tools extension does not work for me in VS 2022. I have Qt installed to my c drive, and when trying to add the version to the extension shown in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ6yb.png

the tool loads for a good 10-20 seconds, crashes, and nothing has been changed

Answer (score 0):

**HOW TO ADD QT VERSION TO QT VS TOOLS**

1. Click "+" button

[image]

2. Click at File Explorer icon on Path
   [image]
3. Select C:\Qt\{The version of Qt you're using}\msvc2019_64\qmake.exe and open it
   [image]
4. You're done! Click ok to comfirm it

**CRASHED?**

Maybe you had a very low-end PC, try install Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I did all that, in addition, i can guarantee i dont have a very low end pc at all, even a low end pc

i mean the cpu itself is a ryzen 9

Comment: in addition, its not visual studio thats crashing, its only the menu